# tool for sizing backup target

Tags: backup, backupexec, sizing

I was wondering if anyone had any recommendations on tools or ways to calculate out what your backup-to-disk target should be sized at for Backup Exec?

I'm working on a project for a customer and we have the data sizing and their desired retention policies and job types (full, incremental) - however I am wondering if there's an easier way to calculate out rough sizing requirements for the backup target. No need to account for de-dupe or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

Run a test of the jobs using the media capacity check and perform pre-scan options. This should give you an idea of the size of the backup sets for the jobs, which should then tell you if you have sufficient media capacity for the jobs on the backup target.